# appendChild() and createElement() Javascript question

Tags: javascript, css, appendchild, javascript-objects, createelement

When I use appendChild() and createElement() in my code, the subsequent styles for the defined CSS IDs are not applied. Can someone tell me why? Here's my code:

```
function searchDone(results) {
    var result = null;
    var parent = document.getElementById('postWrap');
    var child = null;
    parent.innerHTML = '';
    var insertHTML =" ";

    //Paginating Results Links
    resultNum = results.SearchResponse.Web.Total;
    resultNum = resultNum/10;
    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.id = "paging";
    if(results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset != 0){
        insertHTML ='<span><a class="jsonp b" href="#" rev="'+(results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset-10)+'">&lt;</a></span>';
    }
    if(results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset == 0){
        insertHTML += '<span>1</span>';
    }else{
        insertHTML +='<span><a class="jsonp" href="#" rev="0">1</a></span>';
    }
    for(var i = 1; i <= resultNum; i++){
        if((results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset/10) == i){
            insertHTML += '<span>'+(i+1)+'</span>';
        }else{
            insertHTML += '<span><a class="jsonp b" href="#" rev="'+i*10+'">'+(i+1)+'</a></span>';
        }
    }
    if(results.SearchResponse.Web.Total - results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset > 10){
        insertHTML += '<span><a class="jsonp b" href="#" rev="'+(results.SearchResponse.Web.Offset+10)+'">&gt;</a></span>';
    }
    child.innerHTML = insertHTML;
    parent.appendChild(child);
```

I then have some other code which processes my search query via API to Bing (only because Google now charges... )

Next, I use the same methods to insert another div:

```
//Insert Paginating results again
    child = null;
    child = document.createElement('div');
    child.innerHTML = insertHTML;
    child.id = "searchResultsPages";
    parent.appendChild(child);
```

Now I'd like to apply some styles to these numbers. However, when I apply a style to searchResultsPage, like

```
#searchResultsPages{
 float: right;
}
```

I don't get the style being passed on. The curious thing is that if I only insert one of these two elements, everything goes as planned and the style shows up fine. The problem is that I'd like pages displayed at the top and bottom of the search.

Any ideas why this is happening? I think it might have something to do with an element being used twice, but I don't know why this would effect anything if the objects are different.

Thanks.

Comment: `"searchResultsPages" !== "searchResultsPage"`

Comment: Sorry, I should have copied and pasted. The non-agreement between the ID searchResultsPage and searchResultsPages actually doesn't exist. Sorry!!!! I have changed the post to reflect this

Comment: How do you know the styles aren't applying? Have you tried setting something like a bright background color? It's possible that the float:right just isn't behaving how you expect because of the resulting HTML structure.

Comment: I know that they aren't applying because when I take off one of these two divs the style applies perfectly. Also, in Firebug it is not "linked" (for lack of a better explanation)

Comment: Hey guys, I'm just marking the first one to comment as the answer. Turns out nothing was really wrong, just the .css file got corrupted and had to be restored. Weird, I know. Thanks a million, though, and sorry if this question caused you grief! You did point me in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
child.id = "searchResultsPages";

#searchResultsPage{
```

See anything wrong there?  :)

Like an `s`

Comment: Sorry, guys I should have copied and pasted that CSS from my code. That's actually not the problem. Here's a paste from the code #searchResultPages{
 float:right;
}

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique within the page so if you have two elements with id="searchResultsPage" the behaviour can get a bit screwy and the HTML is invalid.  Instead, use a class="searchResultsPage" if there will be multiple elements.

The issue of the missing 's' the other commenters point out is also quite important though hopefully that was just a typo in the question.

Comment: actually I need both DIVs to behave differently, so one div has the ID paging (just something I chose for the moment), and the other searchResultsPages (see code) so that the page would be valid and so the bottom and top paging links could behave differently